# Append ng-select on button click Angular 8

Tags: angular, typescript, angular8

i have a ng-select in my DOM with array values, i want to add new ng-select with same options on click a button "Add",
how can i do it?

here my component code where i take options value from server OnInit:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-recipes',
  templateUrl: './recipes.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./recipes.component.scss']
})
export class RecipesComponent implements OnInit {

  @ViewChild('RicettaTestataForm2', {read: ElementRef}) private divMessages: ElementRef;
  public radioModel: string = '1';
  public Editor = InlineEditor;

  elencoRicette = [];
  elencoRicetteSelezionato = '';
  formRicettaTestata : FormGroup;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private formbuilder: FormBuilder, private render : Renderer2) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.formRicettaTestata = new FormGroup({
      titolo : new FormControl(null,Validators.required),
      difficolta : new FormControl(null, Validators.required),
      tempo_preparazione : new FormControl(null, Validators.required),
      immagine : new FormControl(null, Validators.required),

    });

    this.ritornaElencoIngredienti();

  }

  get ricettaTitolo(){
    return this.formRicettaTestata.get('titolo');
  }

  get ricettaTempoPreparazione(){
    return this.formRicettaTestata.get('tempo_preparazione');
  }

  ritornaElencoIngredienti(){
    this.http.get(environment.laravel_api+'/ricetta/ritorna-ingredienti').subscribe(
      data =>  this.AfterReturnIngredienti(data),
      error => console.log(error)
    );

  }

  AfterReturnIngredienti(data){

    this.elencoRicette = data['ingredienti'];
  }

  addIngrediente(){

  }

}
```

Here is the view section about ng-select, after the plus icon was clicked i want to have two ng-select:

```
....
<div class="col-md-6">
      <p class="h5 spazio-sopra">Ingredienti necessari</p>
      <form #RicettaTestataForm2="ngForm" [formGroup]="formRicettaTestata">
        <ng-select [items]="elencoRicette" bindLabel="nome" bindValue="id" [(ngModel)]="elencoRicetteSelezionato" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone:true}"></ng-select>
        <div>
          <mdb-icon fas icon="plus-circle" class="add-recepies-plus" (click)="addIngrediente()"></mdb-icon>
        </div>
      </form>
      <br>
    </div>
....
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved with a FormArray and for cycle in the view.

In component:

```
formIngredienti = new FormArray([
 new FormControl(null)
]);
```

The FormControl(null) is for have at least one element for the cycle
In my view:

```
<ng-select class="select-ingredienti" *ngFor="let select of formIngredienti.controls;let i = index" [items]="elencoRicette" bindLabel="nome" bindValue="id" [(ngModel)]="elencoRicetteSelezionato[i]" [formControl]="formIngredienti.controls[i]"></ng-select>
```

With formIngredienti.controls i cycle each formControl inside FormArray

In the button action i add one element in FormArray with empty FormControl:

```
this.formIngredienti.push(new FormControl(null));
```

In this way i have add ng-select every time i click the plus button